# Where does debian store screenshots from the install process?

Tags: debian, system-installation

I have just installed debian 10. During the install process there was the opportunity to click the button 'take screenshot' a few times. Does anyone know where to find these again once it is booted up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ScreenShots#Debian_Installer_GUI_screenshots):

> If you complete the installation, **the screenshots can also be found in
>   the directory `/var/log/installer/`** (after the reboot into the installed
>   system).

There are other options available *during the installation* also described.